# How to set default value for non existing <a> or href in list comprehension?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `bs4` for extracting data from HTML files with following `list comprehension`:

```
columns = row.find_all('td')
print([(td.text,td.a.get('href')) for td in columns])
```

Not all the `<td>` has a `href`, so the code does not fly.

How can I maintain the `list comprehension` stile while adding a default value `''` if the tag does not have attribute `href`?

** EXPECTED RESULT **
I would like to get a list of tuples containing the text and the link if there is such a link otherwise empty.

**NOTE:**

As example: every of those columns HTML is like this:

```
<pre><code>
<td class="even" ><strong>12.649.000,18</strong></td> <td class="even" ><a href="/whatever/1.html" target="_blank">Brussels</a></td> <td class="even" ><a href="/whatever/2.html" target="_blank">Belgium</a></td> <td class="even" >blue</td>
<pre><code>
```

---

Expected result for this example would be:
[('12.649.000,18','')('Brussels','/whatever/1.html'),('Belgium',"/whatever/2.html")]

note that all the texts are given back, no matter if they have href in the tag.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Based on your comment I get the point, what expected output should look like - So you have to put the `if-statement` into last position in your `tuple`:

```
[(e.text, '' if not e.a or not e.a.get('href') else e.a.get('href')) for e in soup.select('td')]
```

**Note:** *You have to check for both `if not e.a or not e.a.get('href')` in case that there is an `<a>` without `href` attribute this will lead to `None` value. In terms of readability, the test should probably be outsourced to a function, as also mentioned by @MagicalCornFlake*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ='''
<td class="even" ><strong>12.649.000,18</strong></td> <td class="even" ><a href="/whatever/1.html" target="_blank">Brussels</a></td> <td class="even" ><a href="/whatever/2.html" target="_blank">Belgium</a></td> <td class="even" >blue</td>
<td class="even" ><strong>12.649.000,18</strong></td> <td class="even" ><a ref="/whatever/1.html" target="_blank">Brussels</a></td> <td class="even" ><a ref="/whatever/2.html" target="_blank">Belgium</a></td> <td class="even" >blue</td>
<td class="even" ><strong>12.649.000,18</strong></td> <td class="even" >Brussels</td> <td class="even" >Belgium</td> <td class="even" >blue</td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print([(e.text, '' if not e.a or not e.a.get('href') else e.a.get('href')) for e in soup.select('td')])
```

##### Output

```
[('12.649.000,18', ''), ('Brussels', '/whatever/1.html'), ('Belgium', '/whatever/2.html'), ('blue', ''), ('12.649.000,18', ''), ('Brussels', ''), ('Belgium', ''), ('blue', ''), ('12.649.000,18', ''), ('Brussels', ''), ('Belgium', ''), ('blue', '')]
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but in this way if there is no href there is no tupple. for instance in the list result there is no ('12.649.000,18','') which is the first td tag of the html which does not have any a tag with href

Comment: No problem, but as mentioned, the expected result was not clear. So if I understand right you like to have all `td` as a tuple. Could you add some additional details, so that everybody gets the point and also what you like to do. Would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second item in the tuple to be an empty string by default, you can do what HedgeHog suggested but in a slightly different way:

`file.html`

```html
<pre><code>
<td class="even" >
  <strong>12.649.000,18</strong>
</td> 
<td class="even" >
  <a href="/whatever/1.html" target="_blank">Brussels</a>
</td> 
<td class="even" >
  <a href="/whatever/2.html" target="_blank">Belgium</a>
</td> 
<td class="even" >blue</td>
</code></pre>
```

`parser.py`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("file.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as html_doc:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

columns = soup.find_all("td")


def parse_cell(td) -> tuple[str, str]:
    return td.text.strip(), "" if td.a is None else td.a.get("href")


parsed = [parse_cell(td) for td in columns]
print(parsed)
```

`Output`

```
$ python parser.py
[('12.649.000,18', ''), ('Brussels', '/whatever/1.html'), ('Belgium', '/whatever/2.html'), ('blue', '')]
```

Also, I suggest separating the code out like I did so that it's more readable what you're actually doing.